# PYQgis - add border to legend

Tags: border, legend, pyqgis

I would just like to add a black border of 1mm to my legend generated with PYQgis.

Like this (with QGis):
[image]

How can I do ?

Here is my code :

```
# LEGENDE
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)

# STYLE LEGENDE (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsLegendStyle.html)
legend.setStyleFont(QgsLegendStyle.Title, QFont('Lucida Fax', 18))
legend.setStyleFont(QgsLegendStyle.Subgroup, QFont('Lucida Fax', 13, QFont.Bold))
legend.setStyleFont(QgsLegendStyle.SymbolLabel, QFont('Lucida Fax', 11))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

- Use `legend.setFrameEnabled(True)` to activate the border
- `legend.setFrameStrokeColor(QColor('black'))` to set the color
- `legend.setFrameStrokeWidth(QgsLayoutMeasurement(10, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))` to specify width of the border

[API Documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItem.html#a729d3807fb7f1ff35a6df9febaa46c45)